# TouchPad doesn't work on start unless mouse drivers are restarted or sleep

Tags: 14.04, mouse, touchpad

For some reason my TouchPad drivers don't seem to work until I restart the mouse drivers (`sudo rmmod psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse`) or I put the computer to sleep and then wake it again.
I've checked synclient and xinput when it doesn't work, and both indicate that it is actually on:

```
% synclient | grep -i touchpadoff
  TouchpadOff             = 0


% xinput list-props 13 | grep -i off
      Synaptics Off (304):    0
```

Also, if I restart some settings seem to reset regardless of what the actual setting say (namely `Settings > Mouse & Touchpad > Natural Scrolling` is on and when I restart the Touhpad it switches off, so I have to switch it off to switch it back on).

How can fix this odd behaviour? Or where can I look to find out what is going on?

My machine is a Lenovo Yoga 13

Comment: Try booting off another kernel, see if that works maybe ?

Comment: Just upgraded the kernel to `3.16.2-031602-generic`, still same issue.

Comment: Is this at initial boot?

Comment: Yes it, when I boot it, it doesn't work, then put it to sleep and wake it or restart the mouse, and it works again. If I shut it down and boot it up again (or simply reboot it) same thing happens.

Comment: Why don't you try booting the latest Ubuntu Utopic Unicorn beta live to see if that fixes it? If so, you should wait until later this month when Utopic is released. Also, you should search Launchpad for this to see if it's a reported bug. If not, please report it so it gets fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add the commands to a bash script and schedule it to run at startup? May not be the best "fix" but it should work.

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo rmmod psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse
# Find the command to set natural scrolling and insert here
```

I'm not sure that sudo won't cause issues with scripting, as I'm fairly new at it, but with playing around a bit, you should be able to get it to work. You may have to set the startup to use sudo and create the script without it to get a prompt or set to "Run in Terminal." I'm not sure on that point, but this would automate it, relieving you of the burden of typing the commands each time.

With the natural scrolling, you'll have to determine your button map and reconfigure it as shown here: http://n00bsys0p.wordpress.com/2011/07/26/reverse-xorg-scrolling-in-linux-natural-scrolling/

I know this is more a workaround than a solution, but it should help.

Comment: I've realised restarting the mouse twice fixes the reverse scrolling issue. Everything else seems to stay correct as it should at the moment. As the bounty does not have a long time left, I will give you the bounty as this would solve the issue temporary, however, I will not be marking it as an answer as it's not a fix.

Comment: Thank you for the bounty, and I understand why this would not be marked as an answer, as I even acknowledged the fact that this was only a work around. Hopefully you find a true solution to your question soon.